# How would I find where the acceleration is positive?

Tags: calculus

> The equation is given by the function $s: [0,4]\to \Bbb R$, $s(t)=t^4-4t^3+8t$. Where is the acceleration positive?

---

1. I know the velocity is $v(t)=4t^3-12t^2+8$
2. I know the acceleration is $a(t)=12t^2-24t$

I just can not get the where the acceleration is positive.

Comment: Hint:  $a(t)=12t(t-2)$ and the product of two numbers is positive iff the two numbers have the same sign.

Comment: To find where a function is positive, you first find where it is zero and test values around the zeros

Comment: You could have just asked "how can I find where $a(t)=12t^2-24t$ is positive?" in your post. $s$ and $v$ are totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Hint:*** Just solve the inequality $$a(t)=12t^2-24t \geq 0$$ for $t\in [0,4]$.

Comment: Ok so I solved the inequality which led to t=0 and t=2 but they both come out as positive values t => 0 and t => 2

Comment: Try to draw the graphic of $a(t)=12t^2-24t$ (it's a parable) and then you'll can see when $a$ is positive. Ps: You know that $a(t)=0 \Leftrightarrow t=0 \text{ or } t=2$

Comment: I have it gives me (-inf,0]U[2,inf),  but I keep getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Perfect! You have to intercept it with $[0,4]$ because it is where $t$ 'lives'.

Comment: So the answer should be [2,4) right

Comment: Yes! Maybe $(2,4]$, if you want $a$ strictly positive.

Answer (score 0):

Factor the acceleration,
\begin{align}
a(t) &= 12t^2-24t\\ &=12t \left(t-2 \right) 
\end{align}
Note that the acceleration changes sign at the zeros and $t\geq0$.